# If $C=\{x+y : x\in A\text{ and }y\in B\},$ then $\inf(C)=\inf(A)+\inf(B)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Given nonempty subsets A and B of R, let C denote the set
> C = {x + y : x ∈ A and y ∈ B}.
> If A and B have infima, then prove that C has an infimum and
> inf C = inf A + inf B.

This is my proof:

Since A and B is not an empty set, so C is also not an empty set.
Let a = inf(A) and b = inf(B).

Then, a<=x and b<=y.

a+b <= x+y

Since x+y ∈ C, then a+b <= inf(C)

Therefore, inf(C) = inf(A) + inf(B)

Is this enough for proving, if not any suggestion??

Comment: How did $C$ become a real number? What you've done only shows that $a+b\le \inf(C)$. You have plenty of work left to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\epsilon >0$, then there exists $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ such that, $x$ < inf($A$) +$\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $y$ < inf($B$) +$\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. So, $x+y$ < inf($A$)+inf($B$)+$\epsilon$, where $x+y \in C$. This shows that inf($C$) = inf($A$)+inf($B$).

Answer (score 0):

Your proof has in it the right idea, but it is incomplete.

You need to show:

i) C has a greatest Lower Bound

ii) Greatest Lower Bound of C is equal to a+b where a=inf(A), b = inf(B)

Proof of (i)

C is nonempty as A,B are nonempty.

Let c be arbitrarily chosen in C

c = x+y for x,y in A,B respectively,

Since x ≥ a and y ≥ b

x ≥ a ( add y both sides)

x + y ≥ a + y

And Since y ≥ b ( add a to both sides)

a + y ≥ a+b thus:

x + y ≥ a + y ≥ a + b

c = x + y ≥ a + b

As c was arbitrarily chosen, C is bounded below by a+b

By An application of the Completeness Property of Real Numbers, C has a greatest Lower Bound.

Proof of (ii)

By (i) we have that sup(C) = c ≥ a + b, for some real number c.

We argue via a proof by contradiction:

(RAA) Assume c > a + b

As a+b is smaller than the greatest lower bound of C, a+b is not a lower bound of C.

Find d in C s.t. d < a + b

By definition d = n + m for some n,m in A,B respectively.

So a + b > n + m

but n ≥ a and m ≥ b

and

n + m ≥ a + m ≥ b + a ( by Similar argument used in (i) )

n + m ≥ a + b > n + m

n + m > n + m - contradiction.

Thus c = a + b